# How to fix Context Menu Bar functions (copy/paste etc) after calling setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() on EditText?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing Notepad App in which I've got slider menu showing some text format panel. I toggle view of this panel when user tries to select some text, so I've implemented my menu-toggling code into my EditText's setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() which looks like this:

```
private void manageContextMenuBar(EditText editText) {

    editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }
        // There menu is hidden
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            if (findViewById(R.id.sliderMenu).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                findViewById(R.id.sliderMenu).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        // There menu shows up
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            if (findViewById(R.id.sliderMenu).getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                findViewById(R.id.sliderMenu).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {


            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

When I long click on text my format menu shows up, and also software context menu with paste/copy/cut button on it.

The problem is that because of my "Overriding" context menu functions, they stopped working. I can click the buttons, but they doesn't work.

I hope You will understand my problem
Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `return false` from `onActionItemClicked` method. This way when you click on those menu items Android uses the default actions.

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}
```

From the `onActionItemClicked` method Documentation:
*`Returns: true if this callback handled the event, false if the standard MenuItem invocation should continue.`*